# Divisibility Relation for Spanning Trees of a Graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spanning-tree, laplacian

Let $A = \big[{1\ 1\atop 1\ 0}\big]$, and let $G_n$ be the graph whose adjacency matrix is 
$A^{\otimes n}$. Also let $\kappa(G)$ denote the number of spanning trees of $G$.  From a significant amount of computational evidence, it seems highly likely that that $\kappa(G_n) \mid \kappa(G_{n+1})$ always holds $n \geq 0$. In fact it seems that $\kappa(G_n)^2 \mid \kappa(G_{n+1})$.  I have tried attacking this problem by analyzing the Laplacian of the graph, but this seems difficult because the Laplacian does not behave nicely under tensor product.  I have been working on this for a while so I would appreciate any suggestions on how one might tackle this.

Comment: In the $n=1$ case -- what does it mean that one of your diagonal entries is $1$, one $0$? Does one have a self-loop the other doesn't?

Comment: Yes, I give one of the vertices a self-loop, so that the matrix for $G_n$ can be written nicely. It has no bearing on spanning trees of course. (Also the graph in question is formed by taking all subsets of an n-element set as vertices, and connecting disjoint subsets with edges. The loop corresponds to the empty set being disjoint from itself.) 

Comment: I think you should try the Q-spectrum.  See Thm 2.3 (4), Thm 2.18 and bottom of page 75, Lem 2.20 of "Counting Spanning Trees", http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.36.9128

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is actually as nice as could be.  The number of spanning trees of $G_n$ is

$$
\frac{1}{3^n}2^{n 2^{n-1}}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \big(1-(-2)^{k-n}\big)^{\binom{n}{k}}
$$

This follows directly from the theorems in the comment above.  The divisibility (what a beautiful word!) properties then follow from the formula.

Comment: +1 This was gonna be exactly my answer, but you beat me to it! (Just mentioning for the interested that Runge showed in his Ph.D thesis a version of the Matrix Tree Theorem that holds for the Q-Laplacian, and somehow it is not that well known (though trivial to prove) that this Laplacian is a friend of tensor products....)